# Vertical scrolling with snap/align to div/element/anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I found some lovely websites - http://www.mini.jp/event_campaign/big-point/, http://www.twenty8twelve.com/ and http://www.scozzese.com - all vertical scrolling, and all using a technique that aligns the 'pages' to the top of the browser when you scroll onto a new 'page' - even if you scroll half way into one.

Could anyone give me any pointers e.g. the right terminology/words I could use to search for more info, or a brief intro on the basics behind this technique, or if any jQuery etc plugins exist I can play and learn with?

I did a search of their code but nothing jumped out as how to do it, my Javascript and jQuery are still novice level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Has some native methods like `scroll(), scrollTo(), scrollBy()` which (with some tricks) you can use to smoothly scroll the page. Together with `offsetTop(), offsetLeft()` you can achieve effects like on these sites.

There are also a lot of jQuery Plugins out there (e.g. like this [google hit](http://flesler.blogspot.de/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)) to save you a lot of work with this.

Just search for these Methodnames, this should give you enough hits I guess.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I will go and search/learn about the scroll() methods.

Comment: @DBUK and, did you find something interesting that fits your needs?

Answer (score 2):

Basic scrolling...

```
// Scroll
h = $(window).height();
t = $("mydiv").offset().top + $("mydiv").height();

if(t > h) {
    $(window).scrollTop(t - h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Their scrolling script isn't very smart. If I scroll the webpage down by repeatedly clicking on the down arrow, every time I click, it scrolls back up. So inevitably it doesn't work.

Comment: Ya, all these vertical and vertical parallax sites seem very fragile and held together with string :D. Still, they are fun to play around with. If I learn some things from building one its win win for me, but I doubt I would ever build one in the wild.